# c++ map implementation with good performance

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to map some keys to other data structures, where the list of keys is received from the internet.

`std::unordered_map` is O(1), but worst case O(N) 
`std::map` is always O(log N)

Is there another map implementation with O(1) best case and O(log N) worst case performance?

Comment: you can also implement a map with a sorted vector vector of key value pairs. here insertion is O(N) and searching is O(log N) but caching is better, because no pointers are used in keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best and worst performance of the `std::unordered_map` is very much dependent on the quality of the hash function. The worst O(N) performance is when all your keys map to the same hash-value (i.e., 100% collision-rate). So, unless you have an extremely terrible hash function, you won't really get that kind of worst-case performance.

When it comes to determining the performance of a hash-map, it very much has to do with probabilities and statistics about your data. Basically, you have a distribution of your input data (keys), which is then mapped to a distribution of hash-values. If you know your input distribution well, you can design a good hash function that will map to a *uniform distribution of hash-values*. If your hash-values' distribution is very uniform, then the probability of collisions is low, and thus, the sizes of your buckets (groups of values with the same hash-value) will be small on average, and that will lead to very good average-case performance. You could say that the average-case performance is O(B), where B is the average size of the buckets. The better your hash function is, the lower the collision probability, the lower your bucket sizes, the better your average performance is, and that's what you should aim for.

You cannot, in general, provide a guarantee that you won't get the worst performance O(N), but you can guarantee that the probability of ever striking such a bad case will be very low.

That said, there could be a data structure which stores the elements of each buckets in a way that makes their look-up faster, such as a binary tree or a sorted array. I don't know of any particular container available that does this, but it would reduce the worst case to about O(log(N)), but it would also be an additional burden (constant factor). So, at the end of the day, you'd have to test it to find out for sure.

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, the worst case for `std::unordered_map` is linear, so instead of asking for a better worst case (no such container exists - if it did wouldn't the standard use it, or at least supply such a variation?) let's instead consider what *causes* the worst case and see if we can prevent it.

In this case the `std::unordered_map` is (almost certainly) a hashmap, so the worst case happens *when every item you insert* hashes to the sme value and they *all* chain into a single bucket (effectively making the hashmap a linked list).

So as long as you have even a remotely reasonable hash function the worst case will never happen and you'll wind up with a constant time operation.

Comment: You have got a point about the hash function, but such a container exists: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Separate_chaining_with_other_structures

Answer (score 0):

How about this, just a suggestion.

```
Sudo code:

my_hash = GenHash(key)

std::unordered_map<my_hash, val, Hash = my_hash> map1   <---- Hash function of unordered_map should return its key. i.e. my_hash
std::map<key, val> map2

if my_hash is in map1
    map2[key] = val
else
    val.k = key    <---- assumes key can be stored/found inside the value
    map1[my_hash] = val
```

This way we can stop forming linked lists inside unordered_map that causes O(N). At the best case you fill only the map1. Let me know if the sudo code is not clear.